# On Closure of Product subset of $\Bbb R×\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Suppose that  $\Bbb R×\Bbb R$ has the standard topology.
>
> If $S=\left\{(t,\sin{\frac{1}{t}})\mid t\in R\text{ and }t\gt 0\right\}$.
>
> Show that $(0,0)$ $\in \overline{S} $

Comment: Try to show that (0,0) it's an accumulation point of your set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\forall n>0, t_n:=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$. Then $\sin(t_n^{-1})=0$ such that $\forall n>0, (t_n,0)\in S$. Since $t_n\rightarrow 0$, $(0,0)$ is a limit of points in $S$, in particular $(0,0)\in\bar{S}$

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the same answer I posted.

Comment: Was still typing it when you replied I guess

Comment: No harm done, .

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$. Then $(a_n, \sin(a_n))\in S$.  But $\sin(a_n)=0$ $\forall$ $n$, so $b_n=(\frac{1}{2\pi n},0)\in S$ for all $n$. But $b_n\rightarrow(0,0)$.  Thus $(0,0)\in\overline S$.